# How to include data files in a Ruby Gem?

Tags: rubygems

I'm working on a Ruby gem that uses configurable "templates" to generate HTML. I want to include a basic set of templates with the gem, and allow the users to override them with better/more customized ones. These templates aren't Ruby code, they are "just files" that need to be read from the disk at some point in the code.

I looked over the RubyGems documentation but they make the (not altogether unreasonable) assumption that a gem contains only code (OK, with some documentation and specific meta-data files thrown in for good measure). There's no reference to how to create the equivalent of "/usr/share/..." files.

What is the best practice for including such files in the gem? Should I simply include them as part of the "sources"? If so, how do I discover their path so I can read them from the disk into the template processor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you have a project structure like this:

```
bin/
|__ foobar*
lib/
|__ foobar/
|   |__ templates/
|   |   |__ a/
|   |   |__ b/
|___|__ meta.rb
|___|__ utils.rb
```

In `lib/foobar/teplates` directory you have your template directories or
files.

`lib/foobar/meta.rb` file contains the name of your project and its
version. It's important to keep them (particularly a version number)
synced with the name & the version of the project in your gem
specification. (The best way to do this is read `meta.rb` from Rakefile
to pass values to the spec.)

For example, `meta.rb` may look like:

```
module Foobar
  module Meta
    NAME = 'foobar'
    VERSION = '0.1.2'
  end
end
```

Then write a function that return a full path to the `lib` directory
regardless whether you are testing your project from the sources
directory or the project is installed from the rubygems.

`utils.rb`:

```
require_relative 'meta'

module Foobar
  module Utils

    # Return a directory with the project libraries.
    def self.gem_libdir
      t = ["#{File.dirname(File.expand_path($0))}/../lib/#{Meta::NAME}",
           "#{Gem.dir}/gems/#{Meta::NAME}-#{Meta::VERSION}/lib/#{Meta::NAME}"]
      t.each {|i| return i if File.readable?(i) }
      raise "both paths are invalid: #{t}"
    end

    # [...]
  end
end
```

Having `Foobar::Utils.gem_libdir` function you can always read your
templates in `bin/foobar` file:

```
require_relative '../lib/foobar/utils'

puts Dir[Foobar::Utils.gem_libdir + '/*']
puts Foobar::Utils.gem_libdir + '/templates/a/blah-blah'
```